# implementing adjacency list for graph

Tags: python, adjacency-list

I'm given a graph string like this

```
graph_string = """\
D 3
0 1
1 0
0 2
"""
```

and my function needs to output that graph as an adjacency list like this

```
[[(1, None), (2, None)], [(0, None)], []]
```

but my function is only outputting it like this

```
[[(2, None)], [], []]
```

and i am not sure why?

```
def adjacency_list(graph_str):
    """Takes a graph string and returns the adjacency list"""

    lines = graph_str.splitlines()
    header = lines[0].split()

    if len(header) > 2:
        graph_type, vertices, weight = header[0], header[1], header[2]
    else:
        graph_type, vertices = header[0], header[1]
        weight = None

    edges = lines[1:]
    adj_list = [[] for _ in range(int(vertices))]

    if len(edges) > 0:
        for edge in edges:
            if weight == 'W':
                v1, v2, w = edge.split()
                v1, v2, w = int(v1), int(v2), int(w)
            else:
                v1, v2 = edge.split()
                v1, v2 = int(v1), int(v2)
                w = None
    if graph_type == 'U':
        adj_list[v1] += [(v2, w)]
        adj_list[v2] += [(v1, w)]
    else:
        adj_list[v1] += [(v2, w)]
    return adj_list
    
graph_string = """\
D 3
0 1
1 0
0 2
"""
print(adjacency_list(graph_string))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine, except for the indentation of the final if-else. The adjacency list items need to be added immediately after an edge is processed, so that should be inside the for loop (not outside).

The code below is fixed.

```
def adjacency_list(graph_str):
    """Takes a graph string and returns the adjacency list"""

    lines = graph_str.splitlines()
    header = lines[0].split()

    if len(header) > 2:
        graph_type, vertices, weight = header[0], header[1], header[2]
    else:
        graph_type, vertices = header[0], header[1]
        weight = None

    edges = lines[1:]
    adj_list = [[] for _ in range(int(vertices))]

    if len(edges) > 0:
        for edge in edges:
            if weight == 'W':
                v1, v2, w = edge.split()
                v1, v2, w = int(v1), int(v2), int(w)
            else:
                v1, v2 = edge.split()
                v1, v2 = int(v1), int(v2)
                w = None
                
            if graph_type == 'U':
                adj_list[v1] += [(v2, w)]
                adj_list[v2] += [(v1, w)]
            else:
                adj_list[v1] += [(v2, w)]
    return adj_list
    
graph_string = """\
D 3
0 1
1 0
0 2
"""
print(adjacency_list(graph_string))
```